# swift 4 UITableView Footer, absolute bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I a have created a footer for my UITableView like so:

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 50))
            customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

            commentText = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width - 50, height: 50))
            commentText.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            commentText.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            commentText.layer.borderWidth = 1
            commentText.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            commentText.placeholder = "Enter Comment"

            let submitButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.tableView.bounds.width - 50, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            submitButton.setTitle("Go", for: .normal)
            submitButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.submitButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            customView.addSubview(commentText)
            customView.addSubview(submitButton)

            tableView.tableFooterView = customView
```

and here is the result of it in the screenshot:

[image]

What I am trying to do is have the footer always at the bottom of the screen, is this possible?

Comment: It's better to add FooterView at bottom of screen instead of `TableView` footerView.

Answer (score 3):

A table view footer is always at the end of the table view, after the last row in the table view. This is true no matter how many rows are in the table view.

If you want a view that stays at the bottom of the screen and never scrolls no matter how many rows there are, then you don't want a table view footer. You simply want a view added to the bottom of the screen.

The best solution is to use a `UIViewController` that has your "footer view" pinned to the bottom and a table view added that fills the rest of the screen.

Comment: ill try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just add the footer view at the bottom of the screen view, not add it as a footer view of UITableView, since you don't want the textfield and submit button to move when UITableView scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your custom view to the view itself instead of the tableview.

```
view.addSubView(customView)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if this is a UITableView then `view` is the table view so you can't simply add `customView` since it will scroll with the table view.